# c++ programming function error

Tags: c++, function, parameters, parameter-passing

my full code is (couldn't make it smaller) :

```
/*password is admin*/
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

//-------------------------------
fstream d_base;
char path[] = "library books.txt";

void output(){
//this function for displaying choices only
cout << "***********************************" << endl;
cout << "1. List all books in library" << endl;
cout << "2. List available books to borrow " << endl;
cout << "3. Borrow a Book from library" << endl;
cout << "4. Search For a Book" << endl;
cout << "5. Add New Books"<< endl; 
cout << "6. Delete a Book" << endl;
cout << "7. EXIT The Library"<< endl;
cout << "***********************************" << endl;
 }

 //=====================================================================================================================================================

struct books{
//identfying books with all needed things
int id, status;
string title, p_name, p_address;
string aut_name, aut_nationality;
string date;
};

//=====================================================================================================================================================

//function for choice 1 showing the books (under constructions)

void choice1(){
ifstream show;
char all;
show.open(path, ios::in | ios::app);
while (!show.eof()){
    show >> all;
    if (all == '%'){
        cout << "\n\n";
    }
    else if (all == '.'){
        cout << "\n\n\n";
    }
    else
        cout << all;
}
cout << endl;
show.close();
}

    //=====================================================================================================================================================

void choice2(){

//function for choice 2 (list available books to borrow)
}

//=====================================================================================================================================================

void choice3(){

//function for choice 3( Borrow a Book )
 }

//=====================================================================================================================================================

void choice4(){
char s;
ifstream search;
char idx;
cout << "what book you want to search for : ";
cin >> idx;
search.open(path, ios::in | ios::app);
while (!search.eof()){
    search >> s;
    if (s == idx)
        cout << "book found" << endl;
    break;
    }
search.close();
}

//=====================================================================================================================================================

//for choice 5 to fill books (under constructions)
void choice5(books new_book[],books aut[], int books_number,int aut_number){

//function for adding books to the system 

cout << "how many books you want to add ? ";
cin >> books_number;

    //call the function to record the book

    d_base.open(path, ios::out | ios::app);
    for (int i = 0; i < books_number; i++){
        d_base << "[Book Id]: " << new_book[i].id << "%[title]: " <<     new_book[i].title;
        d_base << "%[Publisher Name]: " << new_book[i].p_name << "%    [puplisher Address]: " << new_book[i].p_address;
        for (int j = 0; j < aut_number; j++){
            d_base << "%[author info]" << "%[Authors Name]: " <<    aut[i].aut_name << "%[Nationality]: " << aut[i].aut_nationality;
        }
        d_base << "%[PublishedAt]: " << new_book[i].date << "%[status]:" << new_book[i].status << "." << endl;
    }
    d_base.close();
 }

 //=====================================================================================================================================================

 void choice6(){

//function for searching for a book

 }

 //=====================================================================================================================================================

int main(){
string choice;
cout << "welcome to FCIS library\n\n";

do{
    output();
    cout << "what do you want to do ? ";
    getline( cin , choice);

    if (choice == "1"){
        choice1();
    }

    //this one for list available books
    else if (choice == "2"){

        choice2();

    }

    //this one for borrow a book
    else if (choice == "3"){

        //not completed yet don't choose 3

    }
    else if (choice == "4"){

        choice4();

    }

    //this one is for adding new books to the list 
    else if (choice == "5"){
        int books_number, aut_number;
        books new_book[10000], aut[10000];
        string password;
        do{

            cout << "you must be an admin to add new books." << endl << "please enter passowrd (use small letters) : ";
            cin >> password;

            if (password == "b")
                break;

            else if (password == "admin"){
                cout << "ACCESS GAINED   WELCOME " << endl;

                cout << "what books you want to add :" << endl;
                for (int i = 0; i < books_number; i++){
                    cout << "id please : "; cin >> new_book[i].id;
                    cout << "title : ";              cin.ignore();  getline(cin, new_book[i].title);
                    cout << "publisher name :";                     getline(cin, new_book[i].p_name);
                    cout << "publisher address : ";                 getline(cin, new_book[i].p_address);
                    cout << "Publish date :";                       getline(cin, new_book[i].date);
                    cout << "How many copies of " << new_book[i].title << " ";      cin >> new_book[i].status;

                    cout << "How Many Authors for the Book ?"; cin >> aut_number;
                    for (int j = 1; j <= aut_number; j++){
                        cout << "author number " << j << " name : "; cin.ignore();   getline(cin, aut[i].aut_name);
                        cout << "Nationality : ";                   getline(cin, aut[i].aut_nationality);

                        choice5(new_book[i], aut[j], books_number, aut_number);
                    }
                }
            }
            else{

                cout << "Wrong password try again or press (b) to try another choice";
                continue;
            }

        } while (password != "admin");
    }

    //this one for deleteing a book
    else if (choice == "6"){

        //not completed yet

    }
    else if (choice == "7"){

        cout << "Thanks for Using FCIS LIBRARY" << endl;
        break;

    }
    else
        cout << "\nwrong choice please choose again\n\n";

} while (true);

}
```

the problem is when i call the choice5() function it gets me errors :

*-IntelliSense: no suitable conversion function from "books" to "books

*-IntelliSense: no suitable conversion function from "books" to "books

-error C2664: 'void choice5(books [],books [],int,int)' : cannot convert argument 1 from 'books' to 'books []

i don't know if it's parameters problem or what!!

the choice5(); function call is in the main in the if(choice==5) after submitting books

and i'm like level 1 at c++ so i'm doing my best to make it smaller

Comment: Where are you calling the `choice5()` function actually and how? I can't spot it. _"(couldn't make it smaller)"_ C'mon! There's loads of unrelated stuff in your code. Check [MCVE] please.

Comment: when you call the function `choice5(new_book[i], aut[j], books_number, aut_number);` the parameters `new_book[i]` and `new_book[i]` you are passing are two `books`, while the function, as you declare it, is expecting two `books *`.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ go to the end...

Comment: @Bob__ Ah, yes. It's a bit of buried in that for loop.

Comment: You can use a [switch statement](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/switch) instead of all those `if`s and maybe you can put all the logic of the fifth choice in a bigger `choice5()` function.

Comment: I would suggest renaming your method to say what they do instead of what choice they are. E.G. choice1() -> showBooks(), choice3() -> listBooks(). It will make your code easier to read. First try and make your code easy to read, then add comments when it is not clear.

Comment: _couldn't make it smaller_ - you couldn't delete code that was not necessary to duplicate the problem? Being a compilation issue rather than runtime, there's all kinds of code you could delete without removing the issue in the process. It's essential to your growth that you figure out how to do this. It will not only help you to communicate better with others but it will also enable you to solve your own problems much more frequently.

Comment: In *your* code you can comment out code to find the statement that is causing the issue.  Use `/*`...'*/` or even `#if 0` ... #endif` to comment out large blocks of code.  Some IDEs have a "block comment" feature.

Answer (score 2):

> i don't know if it's parameters problem or what!!

The compiler tells you exactly what and where the problem is: your call to `choice5`.  The first parameter is an array of `books` and you're passing in a single `book`.

```
choice5(new_book[i], aut[j], books_number, aut_number);
```

`new_book` is an array, `new_book[i]` is a particular `book` in the array.  Same goes for `aut`.

Answer (score 0):

The function choice5(books new_book[],books aut[], int books_number,int aut_number) must receive as first parameter an array of books or a pointer to a struct books. You will have the same problem with the second parameter "aut". To match with the functioon definiton your call shall have this format :
choice5(new_book, aut, books_number, aut_number)